# Windows console FTP - Display username

Tags: windows, ftp, console

Is there a way to get the my username when logged into an FTP client via Windows console `ftp.exe`?

Scenario: I've connected, logged in and successfully and have done a bunch of transfers/etc. I have multiple accounts on this FTP server, and forget who I am logged in as, can check that I am in the right account?

Comment: I'm afraid not. all the FTP verbs related to users and accounts (USER, ACCNT, PASS) are requests sent by the client to the server, containing the info you seek, so if you have forgotten it, the server doesn't have a verb you can use to ask the server to tell you. http://cr.yp.to/ftp.html you might try WinSCP, instead. IIRC it puts the session info in the window title bar.

Answer (score 1):

There are no commands in Windows `ftp.exe` to display a currently logged-in account.

See the [list of `ftp` subcommands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/orphan-topics/ws.10/cc755356(v=ws.10)).

There's even no standard FTP protocol command for that. (If it were, you could invoke it using the [`quote` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-quote)).